# Maximum value of a call option proof

Tags: options, call, put-call-parity

I'm reading Sinclair's Option Pricing and am confused by the proof for the maximum value of a call. It makes sense logically that a call can't be worth more than the underlying, and so:

c <= S

The proof the book uses however is as follows. Say there's a call trading for more than the underlying. Then, I will sell the call, and buy the underlying. At expiration (time T), our profit is:

c-(S_0 -S_T)

I don't understand why we subtract the S_T at the end? Doesn't this imply a huge profit? Say the call was worth 110, S=100, and S_T = 105. Then the profit would be 110-(100-105) = 115. That doesn't make sense.

ALSO, does this just assume that the option that we sold expires OTM, so it's not exercised??

Answer (score 1):

I will try to clarify. Imagine that a European call option is written on $S$ and have maturity $T$. Moreover, imagine it is worth $c_t$ at time $t$. Can $c_t > S_t$? Under the no arbitrage assumption, it can't. To see why, let us build the following trading strategy:

- We sell the call option and gain $c_t$
- We buy the underlying $S_t$

because $c_t > S_t$, we have a sure profit in $t$ equal to $\pi_t = c_t - S_t > 0$.

What happens at expiration time $T$? It can be the case that the option is exercised by the buyer (if he is rational only if $S_T > K$):

- Since we are the seller, we must give him the stock. But we already have the stock in our pocket (recall, we bought it in $t$). So, at time $T$ we will have another profit of $K = S_T + K - S_T$.

It can also happen that the option is not exercised. In this case nothing will happen, and we will hold the stock.

The crucial intuition is then the following: we have a SURE ($\pi_t$) profit and this profit is RISKLESS (we will not lose money in any state of the world). This is indeed arbitrage: since we want to price contingent claims under the assumption that no arbitrage exists, $c_t \leq S_t$.

Comment: @noob2: $K < S_T$. So, there's some positive amount that makes them equal ( if you add it to the LHS ) and he defined this positive amount as $S_t - k$. Atleast that's my understanding.  A very nice proof indeed.

Comment: @noob2: I'm not sure about your typo theory ( which could be correct ) but I also don't think my comment is correct because of the following: (c_t - S_t) is the initial profit of the seller of the call who then owns the stock. But, how can one be sure that $S_T$ is greater than $S_t$. Couldn't $S_T$ be less than $S_t$ in which case the seller of the call could lose money ? So, I'm still a little confused  and not even clear on why part 2) needs to be considered anyway. The initial profit at time $t$ would seem to seal the deal ? Yes, you have call exposure but that call could expire OTM..

Comment: Sorry guys, the small $k$ was just a typo. I intended the strike $K$. Also, in the same inequality, I fixed $S_T$ in place of $S_t$. Even if we bought the stock in $t$, it will have a value of $S_T$ in $T$.

Comment: Very good. The point is clear now. You receive $c_t−S_t$ at time $t$ and then (instead of having to pay anything!) you have a chance to **receive** another amount $K$ at time $T$ and no chance of loss. Which is an arbitrage.

Comment: @Yoda And Friends or noob2: It makes more sense now. So,  if $S_T$ ends up less than $S_t$, then there's no exercise and owner still owns the stock. But couldn't the stock owner then have lost ( in stock price value ) more than he made initially ? Sorry to be such a pest but it's interesting so I just want to get it. Thanks.

Comment: First, even if $S_T < S_t$, nothing prevent $S_T < K$ and so we can still have the option exercised. Second, we do not actually care (as long as we assume stock prices to be positive) about the depreciation. To see why: without the trading strategy, we have nothing in $t$ and nothing in $T$. With the trading strategy, we have a profit $\pi_t$ in $t$ and $S_T > 0$ (an asset) in $T$. You can think the losses as an outflow of money from your pocket: are you losing money (not opportunity) if stock price declines? No you don't.

Comment: aaaah. got it now. As long as $S_T$ stays non-negative, one still made money since , at the beginning, he-she didn't own anything. He-she just wrote a call option to someone.  Thanks much for clarity, wisdom and patience.